# Is El Capitan preventing me from getting the Perl module DBD::Oracle working?

Tags: command-line, perl, dynamic-library, oracle

Let me start by saying I'm not traditionally a Mac user.  I'm still trying to transition from Gentoo, where compiling everything from source was the default state, and the system wasn't actively trying to prevent me from doing "dangerous" things.

I have a new machine running 10.11.  I've gotten `sqlplus` 11.2.0.4 running, and am able to connect to a remote Oracle server with it.  I now want to use `DBD::Oracle` to connect in a Perl script.  I was able to get `DBD::Oracle` to compile/install by manually passing a version to `Makefile.pl` rather than using CPAN (or, more specifically, `cpanm`):

```
perl Makefile.pl -V 11.2
make
make install
```

However, when I run the script using the default Perl (5.18.2 located at `/usr/bin/perl`), I get an error:

```
ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate. Check ORACLE_HOME (Linux) env var  or PATH (Windows) and or NLS settings, permissions, etc.
```

In case the issue lies with the system perl, I installed `perlbrew` and then installed 5.22.0 into `~/perl5`.  Using the perlbrew Perl, I get a different error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _OCIAttrSet
  Referenced from: /Users/jrittenh/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/darwin-2level/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.bundle
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

dyld: Symbol not found: _OCIAttrSet
  Referenced from: /Users/jrittenh/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.22.0/lib/site_perl/5.22.0/darwin-2level/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.bundle
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I've tried:

- both 32-bit and 64-bit Oracle libraries
- symlinking libraries from the specific version (`libclntsh.dylib.11.1 => libclntsh.dylib`)
- fixing hard-coded paths to `/ade`
- creating a 'mesg' folder and made it writeable in `$ORACLE_HOME`
- setting `ORACLE_HOME`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and `PATH` to include `/usr/local/oracle_client` from `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bashrc/`, `~/.bashrc`, and `~/.bash_profile`

Is there something else I can try?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I am using
  Mac OS X 10.11.3 El Capitan, 
  perlbrew 1.74 installed with cpanm & App::perlbrew/0.74
  Perl revision 5 version 22 subversion 1 (installed via perlbrew)
  DBI -- 1.631
  DBD::Oracle VERSION: 1.74
  Oracle InstantClient 11.2.0.4.0 installed at /usr/local/lib/oracle/instantclient_11_2

I can confirm that the only way, so far, I have been able to get DBD::Oracle to work is by disabling SIP (http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/). Any other way I've tried results in the error "failed: ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate. Check ORACLE_HOME (Linux) env var ...".